# Convert Date into MYSQL Date Format

Tags: java, mysql

I have this MySQL `Date` data for 6 months in this format:

`2010-01-01` to `2010-07-01`

But from the UI the *ToDate* and *FromDate* are passed in this format:

`Jan 1, 2010`  and  `July 1, 2010`

Please tell me how can I convert this data into MySQL equivalent format?

Answer (score 3):

First create a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for parsing your input from the UI:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
```

Next parse an input into a `java.sql.Date` (which is unfortunately named and different from `java.util.Date`). So for example:

```
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(sdf.parse(fromDate).getTime());
```

Finally use the `date` to pass to JDBC when making your database queries. Such as:

```
Connection con; // assuming you have a database connection
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table WHERE x = ?");
ps.setDate(1, date);
ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
```